# Cron task with php, how to randomly select a row when "id" = 20, transfer the row to another table and then truncate the old table

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

Cron task with php, how to randomly select a row when "id" = 20, transfer the row to another table and then truncate the old table

Can someone give me some direction on how to write this type of code?

it is mysql, id is set by phpmysql auto_increment sorry!

Comment: What is 'id' and how does it get set? What type of database are you using? You're asking for a lot with zero direction, this is less of a help me question and too much of a do it for me question.

Comment: What part do you need help with? It seems so straightforward it's hard to imagine you need more than a search engine to guide you.

Comment: It sounds like you could do everything with stored procedures/triggers in mysql and not use cron or php. I think you need to do some basic searches and come back with a more focused question.

Answer (score 0):

When `id` is `auto_increment` then you could not randomly select a row, because you select only one row. By default PHP extensions for mysql don't accept multiple statements. So when I understand you right it would be done with two SQL statements

```
INSERT INTO <table2> (<cols>) SELECT <cols> FROM <table1> WHERE id=20
TRUNCATE TABLE <table2>
```